# Is there a way to hide URL from file download prompt on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, download

[image: File download prompt on IE 11]

IE 11 floats the above prompt right after a file download request succeeds. I want to programmatically hide the URL which indicates where the request is handled. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no way to hide the url in the download prompt. I don't find such API to change the IE download prompt.

Besides, I think it's meaningless to hide the url from the download prompt. Even if you hide it from the download prompt, users can still find the url from other places in the page.

Comment: You are right .This was an absolutely meaningless thing I got asked ever. I just needed someone who says this is not possible. Thanks.